# Passing sheets as variables from one sub procedure to another in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post on stackoverflow.  I have two sub procedures in Excel VBA.  The first one, called `Sub IAR_part_2()`, is intended to assign two sheets (by index location) to two variables named sheetname1 and sheetname2.  after assigning the variables I am trying to pass them to my second sub procedure, called IAR_macro, to be processed.  The two sheets are dependant on one another, so sheets 4 and 8 are ran through the IAR macro, sheets 5 and 9, sheets 6 and 10, etc.  My problem is that I cannot figure out how to pass the sheetname variables from IAR_part_2 to IAR_macro.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub IAR_part_2()

    sheetname1 = Worksheets(4)
    sheetname2 = Worksheets(8)

    Call IAR_macro

End Sub

Sub IAR_macro(sheetname1 As Worksheet, sheetname2 As Worksheet)

    Dim h As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim l As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim lr As Long

    Worksheets(sheetname1).Activate

    ' Find the number of the last cell with data in column A and subtract 1 to populate variable i
    On Error GoTo Canceled
    i = (Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row) - 1

    'Switch over to the Code sheet
    Worksheets(sheetname2).Activate

    'While the number of loops is less than variable i minus 1, copy the contents of cells A2 through A29 over and over down the worksheet
    Do While l < (i - 1)

        Range("A2:A29").Select
        Selection.Copy
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A" & lr + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        l = l + 1

        'rest of macro follows from here...
```

Comment: In `IAR_part_2`, instead try `Call IAR_macro(Worksheets(4), Worksheets(8))`

Comment: The current problem is that you're not actually passing the variables in `part_2` to part 1. However, I don't think I understand why you even need the second sub at all; it seems like you could just create those worksheet variables in part 1

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it looked like the variables passed to IAR_macro correctly but then I got an error: Runtime error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: The reason for two subs is because I was going to attempt to make the first sub (IAR_part_2) loop through the worksheet sets and apply the IAR_macro to each set of worksheet pairs

Comment: Your problem is that you're kind of mixing up workbook name and workbook objects. Your `IAR_macro` says it's expecting a `Worksheet`, but every time that you use it in the code itself, you're looking for just the `String` that is the workbook's name

Comment: If you have a type mismatch, then the script is either trying to use a variable of a datatype that does not work with the line. For instance, if you are trying to use the worksheet name as opposed to the id, the name would be a string, not a worksheet variable.    _Edit: Marcucciboy2 beat me to it by 13 seconds! Drat._

Comment: @Thelnternet muhahaha!

Comment: Oh man!  Confused?  Yes!  I will continue to play around with this.  Thank you all for your help, and quick responses :D

Answer (score 5):

Simple example of how to pass worksheet objects to a different sub:

```
Sub Macro1()

    'Declare variables
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    'Assign variables to worksheet objects
    Set ws1 = Worksheets(4)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(8)

    'Call the second sub and pass the worksheet variables to it
    Call Macro2(ws1, ws2)

End Sub

Sub Macro2(ByVal arg_ws1 As Worksheet, ByVal arg_ws2 As Worksheet)

    'Reference the accepted arguments (in this case worksheet variables) directly:
    MsgBox arg_ws1.Name
    MsgBox arg_ws2.Name

    'This will result in an error because you're using the passed argument incorrectly:
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(arg_ws1).Name    '<-- Results in error

End Sub
```

You *must* reference the passed arguments directly.  If you want to use the structure shown in your code, then the arguments passed need to be a string (but this method is NOT recommended):

```
Sub Macro1()

    'Declare variables
    Dim sSheet1 As String
    Dim sSheet2 As String

    'Assign variables to worksheet objects
    sSheet1 = Worksheets(4).Name
    sSheet2 = Worksheets(8).Name

    'Call the second sub and pass the worksheet variables to it
    Call Macro2(sSheet1, sSheet2)

End Sub

Sub Macro2(ByVal arg_sSheetName1 As String, ByVal arg_sSheetName2 As String)

    'Because the arguments are strings, you can reference the worksheets this way
    'This method is NOT recommended
    MsgBox Worksheets(arg_sSheetName1).Name
    MsgBox Worksheets(arg_sSheetName2).Name

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like every time that OP tries to use ws1,2 in the code they want to use it as the workbook's name instead of the object itself. I know you know the difference but you might want to cover it in your answer

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Yeah, that's a good point.  I'll edit my answer shortly

Comment: @tigeravatar - although this answer works as intended, it is a bit wrong - take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53104570/5448626 and congrats for obtaining new knowledge how `ByVal` and `ByRef` works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the two variables you created to your second sub when you call the procedure:

```
Sub IAR_part_2()

    Set sheetname1 = Worksheets(4)
    Set sheetname2 = Worksheets(8)

    Call IAR_macro (sheetname1,sheetname2)

End Sub
```

Comment: After adding the sheets as you illustrated, I am getting an error:  Run-time error '91':  Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: In my IAR_macro, the statement "Worksheets(sheetname1).Activate" is throwing a run-time error 13 - type mismatch.

Comment: @Vityata you are correct. i overlooked putting it in. i corrected my example.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your examples, you have your variables declared inside the function. Normally any variables you wish to use are better implemented by using `option explicit`. Also when identifying sheets, you will have less problems when addressing a sheet by its sheet number as opposed to the sheet name. That way if you need to use a variable, you can use just a integer instead as well.

```
Option Explicit
Dim h as Long, i as Long, l as Long, j as Long, k as Long, lr as Long
Dim x as Integer

Sub IAR_macro()
    On Error GoTo Canceled
    i = (Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row) - 1

    Sheets(x).Activate

    Do While l < (i - l)
```

Sheet ids can be located in the development tool. Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: You've actually highlighted the Sheet's CodeName, which is separate from the Sheet's Index number

Comment: Oh, it is? I was under the impression the values were the same. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: No problem. Nobody really uses them so it's easy to not know the difference :)

Answer (score 0):

This is minimal way of passing the worksheets. As far as they are objects, they are passed by reference by default:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(2)
    Passing ws1, ws2

End Sub

Sub Passing(arg_ws1 As Worksheet, arg_ws2 As Worksheet)

    Debug.Print arg_ws1.Name
    Debug.Print arg_ws2.Name

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not as easy and as simple as many people (mainly those who consider it to be a funny-scripting-language, written by wanna-be-developers) think. Sometimes it allows to write `ByVal`, but it follows its own rules and takes the argument `ByRef`, just to comfort you and make sure you are not going to make an error.

Saw the answer from @tigeravatar here and I have decided not to write a comment under it, but to explain in a different post why it is wrong and dangerous, as far as explaining it as a comment would have been tough.

If you try to write a `Stop` line here from the answer:

```
Sub Macro1()

    'Declare variables
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    'Assign variables to worksheet objects
    Set ws1 = Worksheets(4)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(8)

    'Call the second sub and pass the worksheet variables to it
    Call Macro2(ws1, ws2)

End Sub

Sub Macro2(ByVal arg_ws1 As Worksheet, ByVal arg_ws2 As Worksheet)

    'Reference the accepted arguments (in this case worksheet variables) directly:
    MsgBox arg_ws1.Name
    Stop
    MsgBox arg_ws2.Name

    'This will result in an error because you're using the passed argument incorrectly:
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(arg_ws1).Name    '<-- Results in error

End Sub
```

Run the answer and wait for the Stop line:

[image]

If the `arg_ws1` were taken byVal, then if someone changes the name of the 8th worksheet, while the `Stop` is lighting, then it should still take the old name. It is `ByVal`, remember? Well, go ahead and change the name. Then continue with <kbd>F5</kbd>. Which name are you getting? Why?

The answer is because of the way the Sub is called with parenthesis in the arguments. These force `ByVal` and ignore anything explicitly written.

- [CPearson ByRef vs ByVal](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx)
- [Disclaimer - My Article for how to refer a function ByVal when it is ByRef](http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-how-to-refer-a-function-byval-when-the-parameter-is-explicitly-referred-byref/)